# I understand $\tan(slope) = \frac{\text{difference of elevation}}{\text{horizontal advancement}}$ but cannot figure $\tan(slope) = \sqrt{b^2 + c^2}$

Tags: trigonometry, slope

[image]

I understand the calculation of a slope with the formula
$$
\tan(slope) = \frac{\text{difference of elevation}}{\text{horizontal advancement}} = \frac{3}{5} = 0.6
$$

But a book about Geographic Information System tells me that it has some interest to calculate instead
$$
tan(slope) = \sqrt{b^2 + c^2}
$$
with
$b$ : difference of elevation by meter on the $x$ axis
$c$ : difference of elevation by meter on the $y$ axis

But this last formula, I am unable to understand it clearly and I fail on a digital application.
I can't reach 0.6 and I can't find the values of $b$ and $c$

If I am naive and attempt a
$tan(slope) = \sqrt{5^2 + 3^2}$
it leads to $\sqrt{36}$ = 6, not 0.6...
So I know that I'm doing wrong.

Can you help me? What are the values of $b$ and $c$?
What do they really depict? They are troubling me a lot.

The original text describing the formula I'm trying to understand:

[image]

Comment: I’m guessing, because the question is missing context, that the book is referring to a $3$D angle, where $a=\tan\theta_x,b=\tan\theta_y,$ and the elevation is a third coordinate, say $z.$ But it is hard to say.

Comment: By the way, “slope” is different from “angle,” and $\tan$ takes an angle as input. Indeed, $\tan\theta$ is how we turn an angle into a “slope.” So $\tan(slope)$ is an abuse of language.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews No I see no mention of altitude in the book, but you could be right: it's a chapter about Digital Elevation Model

Comment: Elevation and altitude are essentially the same thing in $3$D geometry.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I added the original text I am studying (in French).
On the graphical, I put in 2D a 3D slope, that's all. But my problem stay the same, I don't understand the formula.